# How can i count the number of unique instances of IP address in the following string in ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing

"10.1.3.1"
"10.1.3.1"
"10.1.3.1"
"10.1.3.1"
"10.1.3.1"
"10.1.3.1"
"10.1.3.1"
"10.1.3.1"
"10.1.3.1"
"10.1.3.1"
"10.1.3.1"
"10.1.3.1"
nil
"10.1.3.4"
"10.1.3.4"
"10.1.3.4"
"10.1.3.4"
"10.1.3.4"
"10.1.3.4"
"10.1.3.4"
"10.1.3.4"
"10.1.3.4"
"10.1.3.4"
"10.1.3.4"
"10.1.3.4"
nil
"10.1.3.10"
"10.1.3.10"
"10.1.3.10"
"10.1.3.10"
"10.1.3.10"
"10.1.3.10"
"10.1.3.10"
"10.1.3.10"
"10.1.3.10"
"10.1.3.10"
"10.1.3.10"
"10.1.3.10"
nil
"10.1.3.11"
"10.1.3.11"
"10.1.3.11"
"10.1.3.11"
"10.1.3.11"
"10.1.3.11"
"10.1.3.11"
"10.1.3.11"
"10.1.3.11"
"10.1.3.11"
"10.1.3.11"
nil
"10.1.3.12"
"10.1.3.12"
"10.1.3.12"
"10.1.3.12"
"10.1.3.12"
"10.1.3.12"
"10.1.3.12"
"10.1.3.12"
"10.1.3.12"
"10.1.3.12"
"10.1.3.12"
nil
"10.1.3.30"
"10.1.3.30"
nil
"10.1.3.38"
"10.1.3.38"
"10.1.3.38"
"10.1.3.38"
"10.1.3.38"
nil
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
"10.1.3.55"
nil
"10.1.3.60"
"10.1.3.60"
"10.1.3.60"
"10.1.3.60"
"10.1.3.60"
"10.1.3.60"
"10.1.3.60"
nil
"10.1.3.66"
"10.1.3.66"
"10.1.3.66"
"10.1.3.66"
"10.1.3.66"
"10.1.3.66"
"10.1.3.66"
nil
"10.1.3.101"
"10.1.3.101"
nil
"10.1.3.102"
"10.1.3.102"
"10.1.3.102"
"10.1.3.102"
"10.1.3.102"
"10.1.3.102"
"10.1.3.102"
"10.1.3.102"
"10.1.3.102"
"10.1.3.102"
"10.1.3.102"
"10.1.3.102"
"10.1.3.102"
"10.1.3.102"
"10.1.3.102"
"10.1.3.102"
"10.1.3.102"
"10.1.3.102"
"10.1.3.102"
"10.1.3.102"
"10.1.3.102"
"10.1.3.102"
nil
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
"10.1.3.103"
nil
"10.1.3.104"
"10.1.3.104"
nil
"10.1.3.106"
"10.1.3.106"
nil
"10.1.3.107"
"10.1.3.107"
"10.1.3.107"
"10.1.3.107"
"10.1.3.107"
"10.1.3.107"
"10.1.3.107"
nil
"10.1.3.108"
"10.1.3.108"
"10.1.3.108"
"10.1.3.108"
"10.1.3.108"
"10.1.3.108"
nil
"10.1.3.110"
"10.1.3.110"
"10.1.3.110"
"10.1.3.110"
"10.1.3.110"
nil

the above string is stdout of:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require "rubygems"
require "fastercsv"


scannedIPs = Hash.new(0)

count = 0
FCSV.foreach("HOUND-1.csv", :headers => true, :skip_blanks => false) do |row|

       text = row[1]
       p text

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require "rubygems"
require "fastercsv"


scannedIPs = Hash.new(0)

count = 0
ips = []
FCSV.foreach("HOUND-1.csv", :headers => true, :skip_blanks => false) do |row|

       text = row[1]
       ips << text if text # you need the 'if text' for the nil objects.

end

num_unique = ips.uniq.length
```

Now, `num_unique` will have the value you need.

**Edit:**
If you want to access a frequency count for a specific IP, do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require "rubygems"
require "fastercsv"


scannedIPs = Hash.new(0)

count = 0
ips = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = 0 }
FCSV.foreach("HOUND-1.csv", :headers => true, :skip_blanks => false) do |row|

       text = row[1]
       ips[text] += 1 if text

end
```

Now 'ips' is a hash of IP addresses and their frequencies.
To access a specific one, do this:

```
ips['192.168.0.1'] #=> 0
ips['10.1.3.110'] #=> a big number
```

Comment: Adrian,
Thank you SO much, you have no idea HOW thankful i am, just one more question:
num_unique gives me ALL Unique IP's 
How can i get the Number of instances of EACH unique IP
Thanks,
-Kamal.

Comment: You can use simpler form of constructor `Hash.new(0)` -- no need to use `Proc` here.

Answer (score 2):

A standard approach to this problem (the problem of counting unique elements) is to use a [`set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Set.html):

```
require 'set'

s = Set.new

s.add('cat')
s.add('dog')
s.add('cat')

p s.size # => 2 (because 2 unique elements)
```

If you don't want to count `nil` as an element, you'll have explicitly skip adding it, or ignore it in your size, i.e.

```
ary.each do |x|
  s.add(x) unless x.nil?
end
```